# How to properly remove NA's and convert strings to title in the same pipeline?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I am trying to drop `NA` values for a df column and then `str_to_title()` all column observations, currently I am using `library(tidyr)` to drop `NA` and `library(stringr)` to convert to title.

Here's the code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

test <- df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na(string_column) %>%
  stringr::str_to_title(string_column)
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in stri_opts_brkiter(locale = locale) : 
  objeto 'string_column' no encontrado
```

Expected output should look like this:

```
# string_column   numeric_column
#  Debit               100
#  Credit              100
#  Debit               100
#  Credit               0
#  Debit                0
#  Credit               80
```

### data

```
df <- data.frame(string_column = c(NA, "DEBIT", "Credit", "Debit", "CREDIT", "DEBIT","CREDIT", NA),
                 numeric_column = c(0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 0, 80,80))
```

How could I adjust the pipeline to get the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `dplyr::mutate` to alter the values of the column `string_column` using `stringr::str_to_title`.

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na(string_column) %>%
  mutate(string_column = stringr::str_to_title(string_column))
```